# code sanitization question

Tags: sanitization

Is it safe to leave data submitted by admin users unsanitized, and only sanitize the data submitted by non-admin users?

Answer (score 4):

You should sanitise all input, trusting your admin users is a naive approach.

Comment: @login - Do you trust yourself? You never make mistakes?

Comment: Assuming that the admin will only ever be you is also naive, I'm afraid!

Comment: What if you are?  Clearly you posted this with an answer already decided in your mind and you intend to be argumentative.  The answer is no, it is not safe to fail to sanitize any inputs to an application, ever.  ESPECIALLY if you are the admin and you don't intrinsically know the answer to this question.  Also, you posted on the wrong site.  General programming questions belong at programming.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to sanitize user data, it should be done for all users, including admin user inputs.

Being an Admin user doesn't mean that the data that they input is always safe.

Comment: @login: Are you sure you will be in admin role for eternity for that tool/app and no other admin will be added to it? and what if someone hacks admin account and inputs something weird?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to not sanitize admin input, unless some part of the sanitizing process will prevent the admin from doing what she needs to do. You have to consider two things:

- Is the admin trustworthy? (I should hope so)
- Is there any risk that someone could become admin without my knowledge/permission? (this is more likely -- someone could crack the admin password or use an exploit to elevate their permissions).

In short, yes, you should sanitize everything -- unless it's such a hindrance on the admin that you're willing to compromise security. Whether you sanitize the admin input or not, make sure admin has a very secure password stored very securely.

Comment: @login are you confident that you will never lose the password and that it's impossible to crack? I'm sure you can trust yourself, but that doesn't mean that your account can't be hacked. Also, you have to consider that you might make a typing error that could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it in wider perspective: If your system at all contains an "admin" account, this means that you have there some special operations that a "normal user" would never see, maybe even some critical, strategic or just dangerous to data/stability/usability of the system.

Admins are humans. Humans make errors. Unnoticed error in critical/strategic/dangerous operation means a catastrophe.

You should sanitize the admin's input even more than a normal user's, because it is the 'admin' who most easily can accidentially trash your system.

Of course, being paranoid with admin input makes little sense if your whole admin-panel is just a textfield that accepts raw SQL queries to execute :)